# Are 'complexity' and 'performance' countable or noncountable?

Tags: word-usage, countability

First of all, I am sorry to ask a question that is worth asking a lot of people, but I could not find an answer that was right for me, so I am posting a new question.

In many scientific journals, e.g., papers published by IEEE, the words 'complexity' and 'performance' appear very frequently.
I also want to use these two words in my paper, but I am wondering whether to consider them as countable nouns or uncountable nouns.

According to many existing papers (searchable in google scholar), Sometimes they are used as being uncountable (e.g., We develop a blah-blah-blah scheme with low computational complexity; The performance of A and B schemes is blah-blah-blah.), sometime as being countable (e.g., We develop a blah-blah-blah scheme with a low computational complexity; The performances of A and B schemes are blah-blah-blah).

On the other hand, according to the [Merriam-webster dictionary](https://learnersdictionary.com/), the word 'performance' is defined as

> Performance:  how well someone or something functions, works, etc. : how well someone or something performs. (and there are both examples for 'count' and 'noncount')

Can I decide whether to use the above two words as a countable noun or a noncountable noun???
For example,

- 'To this end, we develop a heuristic algorithm with ***a*** low computational complexity.' vs 'To this end, we develop a heuristic algorithm with low computational complexity.'
- 'The algorithms developed in [3] and [4] have very high computational ***complexities***.' vs 'The algorithms developed in [3] and [4] have very high computational ***complexity***.'
- 'the performance of our proposed algorithm is better than ***those*** of other baseline algorithms.' vs 'the performance of our proposed algorithm is better than ***that*** of other baseline algorithms.'
- 'We compare the ***performances*** of our algorithm and the other baseline algorithms.' vs 'We compare the ***performance*** of our algorithm and the other baseline algorithms.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that for all your examples, you should use both *complexity* and *performance* as uncountable nouns.

You should be aware that *performance* has more than one meaning. It can be countable:

- The actors gave a good performance last night.

But in your intended meaning, it is uncountable. (The same might apply to *complexity*, but it's more obvious with *performance*.)

Remember that many writers in the IEEE journals will be non-natives, so it's a bad idea to use them as a reference for written English. (Editors and reviewers often let poor grammar slide; they don't have time to catch everything.)

Comment: Very thank you for your comment. Thanks to you, what I have been wondering about for a long time has been resolved.